# How can I link directly to one answer in a question?

Tags: support

I spent some time looking for and mousing over some answers in multi-answer questions, hoping to arrive at a "properties" tab that give me a link to the answer, which is mid to lower page, not the link to the question at the top. (Which is in the URL bar for may browser, and is easily C&P'd from the orange/brown test with the question in it.

I noticed @BESW's answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67253/how-to-transform-a-bunch-of-strangers-into-a-friendly-group) was able to link directly to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50954/4398) that me made to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50946/how-do-i-handle-large-conversations-with-multiple-npcs).

The question link is: `https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50954/4398`

The answer link is:

```
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50946/how-do-i-handle-large-conversations-with-multiple-npcs
```

I am trying to find the "a/50954/4398" bit of the link or properties for the answer itself, to make a better link for a response I have in draft.

How do I find the linkable attribute of the answers to a given question: the nice and easy light brown/orange text isn't there to right click over?

I am sure the answer will provide me with a "Doh!" moment, so I have doughnuts ready to mitigate any damage.

Note. on this rig, I use IE browser, but also use Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a “share” link below each answer. Clicking it will give a little popup containing a link you can copy that goes directly to that post. It's easy to overlook.

In the desktop version:

[image: A cropped screenshot of BESW's answer with a red arrow pointing to the share button]

(Of course, the “mod” link won't be there!)

A neat feature is that the last `/xxxx` in the share URL is your own user ID. It's actually not necessary and can be removed from the URL, but if it appears in the URL posted off-site (say, on Twitter or a blog), then every incoming use of that URL containing your user ID counts toward the “broadcaster” type badges ([Announcer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer), [Booster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/booster), and [Publicist](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist)).

Comment: "DOH!" moment achieved, doughnuts raised in your honor.  Coffee chaser. Thank you.

Comment: … Now I want donuts.

Comment: ... Now I want coffee, but that stupid lab coffee machine is broken again.